# syntax error in mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a very basic star rating system for a simple website. I found this tutorial : [Creating 5 Star Rating System With PHP , MySQL ,Jquery And Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17004356/creating-5-star-rating-system-with-php-mysql-jquery-and-ajax)

however, when I run the same code, I keep getting the following error an no votes get inserted into the database:

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-databaseName.ratings WHERE id='1'' at line 1

This is the code for the page to insert the ratings:

```
<?php
include("settings.php");
connect();
$ids=array(1,2,3);
?>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="rating.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="rating.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
for($i=0;$i<count($ids);$i++)
    {
        $rating_tableName     = 'ratings';
     $id=$ids[$i];
 $q="SELECT * FROM ratings WHERE id='$id'";
$r=mysql_query($q);
echo $q;
if(!$r) echo mysql_error();
$rat = 0;
$v = 1;    // In case there are no records.
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($r))
{
    $v = $row['total_votes'];
    $tv = $row['total_value'];
    $rat = $tv/$v;
}



    $j=$i+1;
    $id=$ids[$i];
echo'<div class="product">
           Rate Item '.$j.'
            <div id="rating_'.$id.'" class="ratings">';
                for($k=1;$k<6;$k++){
                    if($rat+0.5>$k)$class="star_".$k."  ratings_stars ratings_vote";
                    else $class="star_".$k." ratings_stars ratings_blank";
                    echo '<div class="'.$class.'"></div>';
                    }
                echo' <div class="total_votes"><p class="voted"> Rating: <strong>'.@number_format($rat).'</strong>/5 ('.$v. '  vote(s) cast) 
            </div>
        </div></div>';}
?>
</body></html>
```

I did try everything that i thought might solve the issue but nothing worked;

I tried to add back slashes and single quotes for the `$id` and it still throws that error.

I also echoed $q as mentioned on that page and i get the exact same thing that was mentioned on that page!

the only thing that I am a bit suspicious about is the fact that it is not showing the full database name in the error message.

the database name is like this: `CL12-databaseName` but in the error above its showing the database as `-databaseName` and i'm not sure if it suppose to do that or is that something that is causing the error ?

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: => `-databaseName.ratings` that contains a hyphen. SQL's figuring you want to do math (as in minus). Wrap it in backticks or use an underscore.

Comment: @Fred-ii- wrap what in backticks? the databasename?

Comment: Database and/or table, whatever contains the hyphen. A hyphen to SQL means `minus`. TBH, I'm having a bit of trouble following your code, but I know an SQL error when I see one ;) Use ticks `\`` around `CL12-databaseName` or change your structure to use underscores instead. I.e.: `CL12_databaseName` and you should be good to go.

Comment: okay Thanks. its not my code! its just a mess. but it will give me a head start to create what I'm after.

Comment: That didn't work! when I put the backticks around database name i get access denied error.

Comment: Well, errors in a way means some form of success. Don't take errors as being totally bad. Most likely a DB connection issue at this point.

Comment: @Fred-ii- LoVe your theory :D

Comment: I've seen quite a few questions with an access denied error, which usually stems from using the wrong DB and/or a mix of incorrect username/passwords.